# True or false game doesn't work after 1st round

Tags: java, loops

I am new to java, this is my first program I've been developing.
Basically, you enter '1', and that enters you to the game.

Sets level to 1.

Then, it will select a question, based on the level.
First round works fine. After I answer correctly on round 1, It moves me to question 2.

But in question 2, if I answer correctly, it will stick on question 2 and repeat it instead of moving to the next question.

Why is it doing that? I have **level++**?

```
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        gameRoom();
    }

    public static void gameRoom() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Truth and False game!");
        System.out.println("Please write 1 to start, or -1 to exit program.");
        InputI = console.nextInt();

        if(InputI == 1) {
            inGame = true;
            gameProcess(1);
        }
    }

    public static void gameProcess(int level) {

        switch (level) {

            case 1:
                question = tof.getQuestion(1);
                System.out.println("Your question is: " + question);
                System.out.println("Please answer, true or false!.");
                level = 1;
            break;

            case 2:
                question = tof.getQuestion(2);
                System.out.println("Your question is: " + question);
                System.out.println("Please answer, true or false!.");   
                level = 2;
            break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Hey1");
            break;
        }

        while (inGame) {
            InputS = console.nextLine();
            while (InputS != "") {
                inGame = false;                 
                InputS = console.nextLine();
                checkQuestion(level, InputS);               
            }
        }
    }

    public static void checkQuestion (int level, String question)
    {
        Boolanswer = tof.checkQuestion(level, question);
        level++;
        if (Boolanswer) {
            System.out.println("Correct!" + correctAnswers);
            correctAnswers++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect! " + correctAnswers);             
        }

        inGame = true;
        gameProcess(level);
    }
```

The problem might be that, the system can't read the loop while input != "", I may be wrong though, this is the other class:

```
    private String[][] questionsArray = new String[][]
    {
        {"Is sky blue?", "true"},
        {"Is sky green?", "false"}
    };

    private String answer = "";
    private String Currentanswer = "";
    private String question = "";
    private int level = 0;
    private boolean returnValue = false;

    public String getQuestion(int Level) {
        switch (Level) {

        case 1:
            question = questionsArray[0][0];
        break;

        case 2:
            question = questionsArray[1][0];
        break;      
        }

        return question;
    }

    public String getAnswer(int Level) {
        switch (Level) {

            case 1:
                answer = questionsArray[0][1];
            break;

            case 2:
                answer = questionsArray[1][1];
            break;          
        }

        return answer;
    }   

    public boolean checkQuestion(int level, String answer) {

        switch (level) {
            case 1:
                Currentanswer = questionsArray[0][1];
                if (Currentanswer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                    returnValue = true;
                } else {
                    returnValue = false;
                }
            break;

            case 2:
                Currentanswer = questionsArray[1][1];
                if (Currentanswer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                    returnValue = true;
                } else {
                    returnValue = false;
                }
            break;              
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Problem is, when I answer correctly, the second question, it will print nothing. and if I answer not correctly, it will move to the FIRST question.

I only have 2 questions, I know, but I am just testing. Level should go to 3, and print "Hey!" according to the switch cases.

Comment: What is `tof`?.. Please post the code of `checkQuestion` that is called via `tof`.

Comment: please show us all of your code. We can't tell you what's wrong if not all of it is included! :)

Comment: You will also want to learn and use Java naming convention, including giving all variables and methods names that start with a lower-case letter and give classes names that start with an upper-case letter. This becomes much more important when asking others to understand your code and help you.

Comment: But you have only 2 questions. How do you want it to proceed to the next question?

Comment: There also seems some logical problems in your code. As it stands, it mill move ahead of level 2, even if your answer is wrong. Is this the way it's supposed to work?

Comment: FYI, I know this will not solve the issue, but the design of the code really needs work. I don't think it will work in the end. The fact that you are doing recursion inside a while loop will probably kill you sooner or later.

Comment: you might need to add your console output with all your steps till problem appears

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in this loop:

```
while (inGame) {
            InputS = console.nextLine();
            while (InputS != "") {
                inGame = false;                 
                InputS = console.nextLine();
                checkQuestion(level, InputS);               
            }
        }
```

Try to replace `while (InputS != "")` with `while (!InputS.equals("")) {`

Answer (score 0):

You don't support level > 2

```
 public String getQuestion(int Level) {
    switch (Level) {

    case 1:
        question = questionsArray[0][0];
    break;

    case 2:
        question = questionsArray[1][0];
    break;      
    }

    return question;
}
```

Your question = questionsArray[1][0]; stays for any level other than 1 or 2.

If you send level 3 then switch does nothing and previos question is returned,

Comment: That is certainly not the case here. There is no question on level 3. It's simply saying "Hey!" there. See `switch` in `gameProcess` method.